# How can I make it so that text repeatedly fades in only after other text has faded out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, right now, I am using JQuery to try to made a continuous slideshow of text values. However, after some time, more than one start to display at the same time, indicating that my timing is off. I've tried to hide them, but it still doesn't work the way it show. My code currently looks like this. I have 3 strings of texts.

```
<h3 class="s1" style="display:none;"> ONE! </h3>
<h3 class="s2" style="display:none;"> TWO! </h3>
<h3 class="s3" style="display:none;"> THREE! </h3>
```

My function looks like this:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $(".s1").fadeIn(1000);
    $(".s1").fadeOut(1000,function(){
        $(".s2").fadeIn(1000);
        $(".s2").fadeOut(1000,function(){
            $(".s3").fadeIn(1000);
            $(".s3").fadeOut(1000);
        });
    });
},6000);
```

This seems to work fine from the beginning, but after a few seconds (maybe 30 or more), the string start to stack on top of one another. So, the out put I'd want is like:

```
0:01 --> ONE!
0:02 -->
0:03 --> TWO!
0:04 -->
0:05 --> THREE!
0:06 -->
0:07 --> ONE!
```

But, what I get is something like:

```
0:01 --> ONE!
0:02 -->
0:03 --> TWO!
0:04 -->
0:05 --> THREE!
         ONE!
0:06 -->
0:07 --> TWO!
         ONE!
...  --> ONE!
...  --> TWO!
...  --> THREE!
```

How do I write this so the next string will display ONLY after the other has disappeared?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:  Sorry, I did't read the last line, where you asked that ONLY after the other has faded.  Changed to reflect.

As with most things, there is 'more than one way to skin a cat'.  Although I am not sure of your overall application, perhaps the following will help and provide some scalability/versatility:

#### .js

```
var vl = [];

vl.interval = 1000;
vl.fadeSpd = 300;
vl.slide = $('.slider .slide');
vl.cntSlides = vl.slide.length; 

function startSlider() {
    setInterval( function() {
        changeSlide();          
    },vl.interval);
}

function getNextSlide() {
    active = $('.slider .active').index(); 
    if(active == (vl.cntSlides - 1)) {
        nextSlide = 0;  
    } else {
        nextSlide = active + 1;
    }
    return nextSlide;
}

function changeSlide() {
    nextSlide = getNextSlide();
    $('.slider .active').fadeOut(vl.fadeSpd).removeClass('active');
    setTimeout( function() {
        vl.slide.eq(nextSlide).fadeIn(vl.fadeSpd).addClass('active');
    },vl.fadeSpd);
} 


startSlider();
```

As you can see, you can add items/slides and it will loop through them without having to keep writing more instances or layers of code.  Basically:
a.  slider starts with call 'startSlider', setting the time Interval
b.  changeSlide() starts the process of changing the slide, inside of which, it will look for the next slide and compare to the overall slide count, resetting if it gets to the last slide.
c.  hides prior slide with fade(), delays over fade speed/time (vl.fadeSpd), and fades in nextSlide over delay of fade speed/time.

### .css

```
.slider {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px; 
.slide {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.active {
    display: block;
}
```

Not sure this needs explanation, but basically positions each item on top of one another, and hence why having to use a 'relative' container of some type (ie., slider).  You can change the container, but used a 300px width in this example.  There is a lot more you can do with this base.  Having fun styling!  :)

#### main page

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  

<div class="slider">
    <h3 class="slide active">One!</h3>
    <h3 class="slide">Two!</h3>
    <h3 class="slide">Three!</h3>
</div>
```

Just added the container, so the absolute, stacked items/slides have some type of relative positioning/parameters.

Sorry if this doesn't help given your application, but perhaps someone will glean something from it.